# Is it possible to read specific files under a single directory uisng PySpark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I have the following situation where there are multiple files under a directory as follows:

```
AT_BookingRequests_16102021_05082022.xlsx
AT_Bookings_16102021_05082022.xlsx
SWE_BookingRequests_08042019_05082022.xlsx
SWE_Bookings_06082020_05082021.xlsx
SWE_Bookings_06082021_05082022.xlsx
SWE_Bookings_08042019_05082020.xlsx
```

Now I need to load them to two different tables (say booking_request and bookings).
Data in the folder gets loaded everyday and I am required to read only new records that gets loaded each day.

Till now I thought of storing the file names in the specific tables and

```
#  List all files under the base folder
fileList =[]
for x in dbutils.fs.ls(base_source_path):
  fileList.append(x)

booking_requests_files = []
bookings_files = []
for i in fileList: 
  file = i[0].split('/')[-1]
  if 'BookingRequests' in file:
    booking_requests_files.append(file)
  else:
    bookings_files.append(file)

loaded_booking_req_files = spark.sql(f"select distinct filename from {booking_requests_table}").rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()

loaded_bookings_files = spark.sql(f"select distinct filename from {bookings_table}").rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()

for file in booking_requests_files:
  filepath = base_source_path + '/' + file
  print(filepath)
  if file not in loaded_booking_req_files:
    df_req_read = spark.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel")\
    .option("header", "true")\
    .load(filepath)

for file in bookings_files :
  filepath = base_source_path + '/' + file
  print(filepath)
  if file not in loaded_bookings_files :
    df_req_read = spark.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel")\
    .option("header", "true")\
    .load(filepath)
```

What I am trying to achieve is to avoid iterating through the files as can be seen. I have already tried passing the all the files as list but it fails.

Also, what will be the best approach to implement this?

Comment: Specifically what error were you getting? Without knowing more about your situation, for example, are you getting daily drops of new files to your landing folder or are the files being updated, I recommending checking out Structured streaming as Alex L suggested below.

Answer (score 1):

seems like streaming to me something like a streaming approach. There are multiple ways of doing what you need. I had a similar thing in both batching and streaming. Our cases:

1. Batching: We were using a flag system. Every time a file was processed we were creating an empty file with the original filename. So, next time when we process we check if the file was already processed or not.
2. Structured streaming: Using checkpoint. Here are so many things to share but if you don't know about structured streaming you can read the documentation: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html

Hope that I could help you.